# Wrong CSS mime type with Roundcube 0.5 beta and nginx

Tags: debian, nginx, roundcube

I'm running into a CSS problem. This is a setup based on Debian Squeeze (nginx/0.7.67, php5/cgi) on which I installed the latest Roundcube 0.5 beta.

PHP is properly processed, login works fine but the CSS files are not loaded and Firefox is throwing the following errors:

> Error: The stylesheet 
>   https://webmail.example.net:10443/roundcube/skins/default/common.css?s=1290600165
>
> was not loaded because its MIME type,
>   "text/html", is not "text/css". Source
>   File:
>   https://webmail.example.net:10443/roundcube/?_task=login
>   Line: 0
>
> Error: The stylesheet 
>   https://webmail.example.net:10443/roundcube/skins/default/mail.css?s=1290156319
>
> was not loaded because its MIME type,
>   "text/html", is not "text/css". Source
>   File:
>   https://webmail.example.net:10443/roundcube/?_task=login
>   Line: 0

As far as I understand, nginx doesn't see the .css extension (because ofthe ?s= argument) and thus set the mime type with the default value, being text/html.

Should I fix this in nginx (and how ?) or is it roundcube's related ?

**Edit**: It seems that it's nginx related. The content-type isn't set for any other type than text/html.
I had to include manually the following declarations to force CSS and JS content-types. That's ugly, and I never had the problem before... any idea ?

> ```
> location ~ \.css {
>     add_header  Content-Type    text/css;
> }
> location ~ \.js {
>     add_header  Content-Type    application/x-javascript;
> }
> ```

Comment: Nginx will see the .css extension just fine, most likely you haven't included the mime.types file and thus Nginx does not know any mime types.

Comment: not likely... debian default configuration includes the mime.type file in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf as follow:  http {  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;

Answer (score 1):

Same for me, Mime types are correct, but after I used this

```
location ~ \.css {
    add_header  Content-Type    text/css;
}
location ~ \.js {
    add_header  Content-Type    application/x-javascript;
}
```

I get a 404 not found error, remove that code, the css shows up fine, but fire fox won't load it due to wrong mime type

I'm on Nginx 0.9.3

FOund the problem!
Looks like We we're running everything through PHP Processor
Adding this:

```
if ($uri ~ "\.php"){
fastcgi_pass php-fpm;
}
```

In the `location ~ ^\.php$ {` section worked for me!
Thanks!